# Was Catcher in the Rye autobiographical?

Tags: j-d-salinger, the-catcher-in-the-rye

Was *Catcher in the Rye* by J.D. Salinger in any way based on Salinger's earlier life, like the works of Charles Dickens?

Answer (score 3):

Salinger's daughter said in her book, Dreamcatcher, that the scene where the nuns ask Holden if he is Catholic or not, is a thinly veiled reproduction of J.D. Salinger's Jewish heritage. He did not like inquiries--of any kind, as he was reclusive--into what religion he was, regardless of acceptance or anti-Semitism.

One more similarity: it's no coincidence Holden hates the movies, as he references his brother D.B. as "prostituting himself out there in Hollywood." According to Margaret Salinger, her father was so incensed by Hollywood's treatment of his story "Uncle Wiggly in Connecticut" that he has refused to sell the movie rights to any of his stories to Hollywood.  It is reported that his last will and testament has a stipulation blocking any Hollywood adaptations of his works after his death.

According the IMDb the movie, Foolish at Heart, on which his story was based, was nominated for two Oscars.